# Duplicate session Records - Ending all but latest record

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, duplicates, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to identify duplicate sessions in a log table on sql server.

A user should only ever have one open login session at a time however sometimes when the app crashes, it leaves user sessions open causing issues.

I want to find all users with multiple open sessions (end date would be null) and then put a end date on all but the latest open session.

Example table columns would be
Username, start_time, end_time

Example data

```
henrya  2023-03-30 11:15:00.493 NULL
henrya  2023-03-30 11:00:00.493 NULL
henrya  2023-03-30 10:15:00.493 10:30:00.493
qwertya  2023-03-30 12:15:00.493 NULL
qwertya  2023-03-30 12:00:00.493 NULL
qwertya  2023-03-30 10:15:00.493 NULL
```

I am having difficulty with the update script to end all but the latest session per user.

Comment: You've told us what you want, but what are you asking? What is stopping you achieving your goals? What is the difficulty you are having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all extra rows you can use `ROW_NUMBER`. You can use an updatable CTE or subquery for this, and do the update directly on that without re-joining

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
      rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Username ORDER BY start_time DESC)
    FROM YourTable
    WHERE end_time IS NULL
)
UPDATE cte
SET end_time = SYSUTCDATETIME()
WHERE rn > 1;
```

Comment: How would i amend the select to only bring back rows having count of more than 1 i.e duplicate open sessions

Comment: Sorry meant to do `> 1` not `= 1` also needs descending sort